# SQL Left joining two datasets. One with monthly data one with daily

Tags: sql, sas

Trying to join two datasets. One with monthly shares outstanding and the other with daily share prices. I need the daily prices to match up with their monthly shares outstanding so I can multiply them together.

Sample data are two sets. Prices variables are: `date`,  `firm`,  `price`. Shareout variables are `date`, `firm`,  `Shareout`.

The merged data set should have add `Shareout` to `prices`. Shares outstanding are in monthly terms are therefore should only change at the end of each month. Right now the tables merge but `sharesout` are all null.

```
prices :
Date        FIRM   PRICE 
 1/1/2013    1       2  
 2/1/2013    1    2.05  
 3/1/2013    1    2.04

shareout :
Date      FIRM   SHAREOUT            
1/1/2013   1     200,000    
1/2/2013   1     215,000    
1/3/2013   1     250,000 

New Table - temp1 : 
Date    FIRM   Price SHAREOUT     
1/1/2013  1     2    200,000
2/1/2013  1   2.05   200,000
3/1/2013  1   2.04   200,000
```

The code is:

```
proc sql;
create table temp1 as 
select a.*, b.shareout from index.prices as a 
left join index.shareout as b on a.firm=b.firm and month(a.date)=month(b.date);
quit;
```

What is generated:

```
Date     Firm Price Shareout
1/1/2013  1     2      -

Proc Contents table1

ASX Char 10 $CHAR10. $CHAR10. 
CLOSE Num 8 BEST7. BEST7. 
Date Num 8 YYMMDD10. YYMMDD10. 
HI Num 8 BEST7. BEST7. 
LOW Num 8 BEST7. BEST7. 
Tick Num 8 BEST5. BEST5. 

Proc Contents table2

asx Char 6 $CHAR10. $6. 
date Num 8 DDMMYYS10.   
shareout Num 8 BEST12. BEST32. 
year Num 8 BEST12. BEST32.
```

Cheers.

Comment: Please edit your question and add sample data and desired results.  I, for one, have no idea what this means:  "I need the daily prices to match up with their monthly shares outstanding so I can multiply them together".

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code.  Without seeing the data, we will not be able to help your debug this.

Comment: Alright I'll get the data up.  The issue is the shares outstanding are null values after the join.  I can't really see any reason why this would happen.

Comment: which rdbms, is it oracle or mysql or sqlserver

Comment: It would help to see the list of fields in each table.

Comment: The fields have been put up there

Comment: Post a proc contents from each data set.

Comment: Have done. Think that's what you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be logically correct, you should join on year and month match:

```
month(a.date)=month(b.date) and year(a.date)=year(b.date)
```

However, what you supply as PROC CONTENTS output does not match with your code: no `firm` field in source tables column listing, so I guess you're not accurate in your assumptions about data nor in sample data and output provided.

I suggest you simply check your data e.g. like this:

```
proc sql;
select distinct year(date), month(date) from index.prices where firm=1;
select distinct year(date), month(date) from index.shareout where firm=1;
quit;
```

Comment: Sorry should have been more clear. ASX and Firm are the same thing. Just changed it when I posted the code to be more clear for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for that. Checked my data and I didn't think the match by Firm was case sensitive, definitely a dumb move. Googled it early and I thought SAS wasn't case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see how you can have a case sensitivity issue with a character column storing a number.  1 is 1 in both lower and upper case.  I suspect your problem might be leading spaces if Firm is the problem column.

You could try compressing Firm the join e.g.

`left join index.shareout as b 
on compress(a.firm) = compress(b.firm) 
and month(a.date)=month(b.date);`

This will remove any spaces from both instances of Firm when joining the tables.